# How to select from the second and third table and group the data according to transaction date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables and I want to (CREATE VIEW) SELECT data from table2 and table 3 then group those data according to the MONTH AND YEAR that the money is deposited and the cheque is being issued. But I didn't meet my  expected results.

Here is my code

```
1. tbl_deposits
+---------+------------------+--------+----------+
| transId | date(YYYY-MM-DD) | bankId |  amount  |
+---------+------------------+--------+----------+
|   1     |    2019-04-12    |    1   |   100.00 |
|   2     |    2019-04-11    |    1   |   200.00 |
|   3     |    2019-05-07    |    3   |   500.00 |
|   4     |    2019-05-11    |    3   |   300.00 |
|   5     |    2019-05-13    |    1   | 1,000.00 |
+---------+------------------+--------+----------+

2. tbl_bankAccount
+--------+----------+
| bankId | bankName |
+--------+----------+
|   1    |  Bank 1  |
|   2    |  Bank 2  |
|   3    |  Bank 3  |
+--------+----------+

3. tbl_chequeIssue
+------------+-------------+--------+--------+
| checkIdNum | date_issued | bankId | amount |
+------------+-------------+--------+--------+
|    1       | 2019-05-08  |   1    |  50.00 |
|    2       | 2019-05-14  |   3    |  20.00 |
|    3       | 2019-05-19  |   3    |  10.00 |
|    4       | 2019-06-01  |   1    |  15.00 |
+------------+-------------+--------+--------+
```

I tried this code but it didn't worked

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.Date, '%b , %Y') AS Date_Deposit,b.BankName AS 
Bank_Name, a.Amount AS Deposited_Amount,
DATE_FORMAT(a.trans_time, '%b , %Y') AS Check_Issued,b.BankName, c.Amount 
AS Amount_Issued
FROM tbl_deposits a
JOIN tbl_bankaccount b
ON a.bankaccount_id = b.bankaccount_id
JOIN tbl_checkissue c
ON a.bankaccount_id = c.bankaccount_id
GROUP BY 
MONTH(c.trans_time),YEAR(c.trans_time),
MONTH(a.Date),YEAR(a.date),b.BankName
ORDER BY a.Date ASC,b.BankName
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
+--------------+----------+------------+--------------+----------+---------------+
| Date_Deposit | BankName | Dep_Amount | Check_Issued | BankName | Amount_issued |
+--------------+----------+------------+--------------+----------+---------------+
| Apr, 2019    |  BANK 1  |    300.00  |              |          |               |
| May, 2019    |  BANK 1  |  1,000.00  |  May, 2019   |  BANK 1  |    50.00      |
| May, 2019    |  BANK 3  |    800.00  |  May, 2019   |  BANK 3  |    30.00      |
|              |          |            |  June, 2019  |  BANK 1  |    15.00      |
+--------------+----------+------------+--------------+----------+---------------+
```

ACTUAL RESULT base on my mysql code

```
+--------------+----------+------------+--------------+----------+---------------+
| Date_Deposit | BankName | Dep_Amount | Check_Issued | BankName | Amount_issued |
+--------------+----------+------------+--------------+----------+---------------+
| Apr, 2019    |  BANK 1  |    100.00  |   May, 2019  |  BANK 1  |    50.00      |
| Apr, 2019    |  BANK 1  |    100.00  |   May, 2019  |  BANK 1  |    15.00      |
| May, 2019    |  BANK 3  |    500.00  |   May, 2019  |  BANK 3  |    20.00      |
| May, 2019    |  BANK 1  |  1,000.00  |   May, 2019  |  BANK 1  |    50.00      |
| May, 2019    |  BANK 1  |  1,000.00  |   May, 2019  |  BANK 1  |    15.00      |
+--------------+----------+------------+--------------+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: There's a missing column in your query. `DATE_FORMAT(a.trans_time, '%b , %Y')`

Comment: I cannot make sense of your expected output. Why for example does the first row have deposits for april and issued for may on the same row? And how do have a relationship between bank 1 and bank 3 in the second row?

Comment: Hi P.Salmon /Sorry my mistake..i edit already the expected output,,tnx for your time,hope you can help me

Comment: My bad @P.Salmon , I edited the table previously and saw the empty row but thought it was a mistake so I removed them. I'm sorry Tzuy.

Comment: no problem @tcadidot0 ,tnx for ur time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%b , %Y') Date_Deposit,
       c.BankName,SUM(a.amount) AS Dep_amount,
       Check_issued,c.BankName,SUM(b.amount) AS Amount_issued
    FROM tbl_deposits a 
    LEFT JOIN --one is doing left joining
     (SELECT date_issued,
             DATE_FORMAT(date_issued, '%b , %Y') Check_issued,
             bankid,
             SUM(amount) AS amount 
          FROM tbl_chequeissue 
      GROUP BY bankid, DATE_FORMAT(date_issued, '%b , %Y')) b 
      ON a.bankId=b.bankId  
      AND MONTH(a.date)=MONTH(date_issued) 
      AND YEAR(a.date)=YEAR(date_issued) 
      LEFT JOIN tbl_bankaccount c ON a.bankid=c.bankid
GROUP BY a.bankid, DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%b , %Y')
UNION --union these two query
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%b , %Y') Date_Deposit,
       c.BankName,SUM(a.amount) AS Dep_amount,
       Check_issued,c.BankName,SUM(b.amount) AS Amount_issued
    FROM tbl_deposits a 
    RIGHT JOIN --another is doing right joining
     (SELECT date_issued,
             DATE_FORMAT(date_issued, '%b , %Y') Check_issued,
             bankid,
             SUM(amount) AS amount 
          FROM tbl_chequeissue 
      GROUP BY bankid, DATE_FORMAT(date_issued, '%b , %Y')) b 
      ON a.bankId=b.bankId  
      AND MONTH(a.date)=MONTH(date_issued) 
      AND YEAR(a.date)=YEAR(date_issued) 
          LEFT JOIN tbl_bankaccount c ON a.bankid=c.bankid
GROUP BY a.bankid, DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%b , %Y');
```

Performing `UNION` on two similar query only differentiated by the `JOIN` operators.

Comment: tnx @tcadidot0,,i will try it when i got home.i am struglling this one for days..hope it will work..tnku so much for ur time